# JasperReport creation with image fails to create temporary file on Windows Vista, 7 or Server 2008

Tags: image, windows-7, jasper-reports, temporary-files

We are getting the following error while generating a Jasper report when running our app on some machines with Windows Vista, Windows 7 or Windows 2008:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't create output stream!
>   at br.com.oobj.relatorio.RRelatorioJasper.gerarJasperPrint(RRelatorioJasper.java:61)
>   at br.com.oobj.relatorio.RRelatorioJasper.gerarJasperPrint(RRelatorioJasper.java:44)
>   at br.com.oobj.cte.dacte.RGerarDacte.gerarJasperPrint(RGerarDacte.java:153)
>   at br.com.oobj.cte.dacte.RGerarDacte.gerarJasperPrint(RGerarDacte.java:66)
>   at br.com.oobj.me.impressao.GeradorDacte.gerarDAME(GeradorDacte.java:55)
>   at br.com.oobj.me.impressao.GeradorDameDelegator.gerarDAME(GeradorDameDelegator.java:23)
>   at br.com.oobj.me.impressao.ServicoImpressao.processar(ServicoImpressao.java:117)
>   at br.com.oobj.me.impressao.ConsumidorImpressao.novaMensagem(ConsumidorImpressao.java:71)
>   at br.com.oobj.util.fila.ConsumidorNotificante.run(ConsumidorNotificante.java:229)
>   at br.com.oobj.me.impressao.ConsumidorImpressao.run(ConsumidorImpressao.java:47)
>   Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't create output stream!
>   at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRJdk14ImageEncoder.encode(JRJdk14ImageEncoder.java:90)
>   at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRAbstractImageEncoder.encode(JRAbstractImageEncoder.java:74)
>   at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRImageLoader.loadImageDataFromAWTImage(JRImageLoader.java:166)
>   at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRImageRenderer.getInstance(JRImageRenderer.java:207)
>   at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRImageRenderer.getInstance(JRImageRenderer.java:190)
>   at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillImage.evaluateImage(JRFillImage.java:901)
>   at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillImage.evaluate(JRFillImage.java:870)
>   at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.evaluate(JRFillElementContainer.java:275)
>   at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.evaluate(JRFillBand.java:426)
>   at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillBandNoOverflow(JRVerticalFiller.java:424)
>   at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillPageHeader(JRVerticalFiller.java:388)
>   at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportStart(JRVerticalFiller.java:249)
>   at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:113)
>   at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:891)
>   at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:814)
>   at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fillReport(JRFiller.java:89)
>   at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:601)
>   at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:517)
>   at br.com.oobj.relatorio.RRelatorioJasper.gerarJasperPrint(RRelatorioJasper.java:58)
>   ... 9 more
>   Caused by: javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't create output stream!
>   at javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(Unknown Source)
>   at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRJdk14ImageEncoder.encode(JRJdk14ImageEncoder.java:86)
>   ... 27 more
>   Caused by: javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't create cache file!
>   at javax.imageio.ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(Unknown Source)
>   ... 29 more
>   Caused by: java.io.IOException: The system cannot find the path specified
>   at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
>   at java.io.File.checkAndCreate(Unknown Source)
>   at java.io.File.createTempFile(Unknown Source)
>   at javax.imageio.stream.FileCacheImageOutputStream.(Unknown Source)
>   at com.sun.imageio.spi.OutputStreamImageOutputStreamSpi.createOutputStreamInstance(Unknown Source)
>   ... 30 more

The report references an external JPG image. The application runs as a windows service. I already tried to start the service with an administrator user, with no success.

In some machines, we solved the issue by relocating the image to a different drive other than C:

Will be very grateful with any help you can bring.

Thanks,
Jonathas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Windows 2008 has different defaults for some system directives concerning services.

While running the application in user mode (i.e. running from within a windows user session), the problem does not verify.

Also, if we moved the file to a drive other than the drive on which windows is installed, the problem does not occur.

It's not exactly a solution (I didn't figure out exactly what system directive to change), but I belive this information could eventually help.